# Finding out the file name of the running batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Inside a windows batch file I'd like to figure out what the fully qualified path name of this batch file is.

I have tried `%0` but this does only gave me the typed command (e.g. just the file name without path or extension).

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking.  %0 is what you typed to launch a script.  Is the script launching another ? Is it linked to another ?  More info please.

Comment: If you just use %0 you won't get the fully qualified path name. In order to refere to your batch file out of an other applications %0 is not enough.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
echo %~f0
```

works for me.

see `for /?` from `cmd` and read about variable substitution.

Answer (score 35):

For your information,

You will need to enable command extends, which is not exists before Win 2000 (I don't know NT4)

SEE: cmd.exe /?

```
/E:ON   Enable command extensions (see below)
/E:OFF  Disable command extensions (see below)
```

command extensions is enabled by default on windows.

Another help I suggest to read is the FOR command.
It contains complete meaning for those flag.

SEE: `for /?` from `cmd`

```
In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced.
You can now use the following optional syntax:

    %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
    %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
    %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
    %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
    %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
    %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
    %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
    %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
    %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
    %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable and expands %I to the
                   fully qualified name of the first one found.
                   If the environment variable name is not
                   defined or the file is not found by the
                   search, then this modifier expands to the
                   empty string

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

    %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
    %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
    %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
    %~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable for %I and expands to the
                   drive letter and path of the first one found.
    %~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line

In the above examples %I and PATH can be replaced by other valid
values.  The %~ syntax is terminated by a valid FOR variable name.
Picking upper case variable names like %I makes it more readable and
avoids confusion with the modifiers, which are not case sensitive.
```

Comment: just replace I with 0

Answer (score 8):

`%CD%` gives the current directory.

`%~dp0` will give you the directory the script is in.

IE: script in `c:\folder`, I call it from `c:\otherfolder`

`%CD%` = `C:\otherfolder`

`%~dp0` = `c:\folder`

(I'm  99% sure I've got those the right way round, but not got windows to check on atm).

edit: and from there, using the one you've already got, you should be able to get the batch file name

Answer (score 1):

```
%~f0
```

```
%~dpnx0
```

Either of the above gives the fully-qualified path.  Enclose it in double quotes in case the path contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Calling script `FIRST.BAT`:

```
call second.bat %0 parameter-a parameter-b
```

Called script `SECOND.BAT`:

```
echo The name of this called script should be "SECOND", proof: %~n0
echo The 1st parameter passed should be "FIRST", proof: %1
shift
echo The name of the calling script should be "FIRST", proof: %~n0
echo The 1st parameter should be "parameter-a", proof: %1
```

Comment: I hope that my formatting improvements were approximately correct.