# What is the best way to do a substring in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, substring

I want to get the name of the currently running batch file **without** the file extension.

Thanks to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343518/finding-out-the-file-name-of-the-running-batch-file), I have the file name **with** the extension... but what is the best way to do a substring in a batch file?

Or is there another way to get the file name w/o the extension?

It is safe to assume 3 letter extensions in this scenario.

Answer (score 452, accepted):

Well, for just getting the filename of your batch the easiest way would be to just use `%~n0`.

```
@echo %~n0
```

will output the name (without the extension) of the currently running batch file (unless executed in a subroutine called by `call`). The complete list of such “special” substitutions for path names can be found with `help for`, at the very end of the help:

> In addition, substitution of FOR
>   variable references has been enhanced.
>   You can now use the following optional
>   syntax:
>
> ```
> %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
> %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
> %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
> %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
> %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
> %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
> %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
> %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
> %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
> %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
> %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
>                environment variable and expands %I to the
>                fully qualified name of the first one found.
>                If the environment variable name is not
>                defined or the file is not found by the
>                search, then this modifier expands to the
>                empty string
> ```
>
> The modifiers can be combined to get
>   compound results:
>
> ```
> %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
> %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
> %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
> ```

To precisely answer your question, however: Substrings are done using the `:~start,length` notation:

```
%var:~10,5%
```

will extract 5 characters from position 10 in the environment variable `%var%`.

**NOTE:** The index of the strings is zero based, so the first character is at position 0, the second at 1, etc.

To get substrings of argument variables such as `%0`, `%1`, etc. you have to assign them to a normal environment variable using `set` first:

```
:: Does not work:
@echo %1:~10,5

:: Assign argument to local variable first:
set var=%1
@echo %var:~10,5%
```

The syntax is even more powerful:

- `%var:~-7%` extracts the last 7 characters from `%var%`
- `%var:~0,-4%` would extract all characters except the last four which would also rid you of the file extension (assuming three characters after the period [`.`]).

See `help set` for details on that syntax.

Comment: Substring extraction doesn't work with FOR loop variables either so you'll have to do as follows (\r\n in the code mean line breaks because SO seem not allowing line breaks in comments): `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION \r\n
for /f %%s in ('set') do ( \r\n
 set tmp=%%s \r\n
 echo !tmp:~-3! \r\n
)`

Comment: @Fr0sT why do you have to do this for `FOR` loops?

Comment: @Adrian why not? `FOR` is a cornerstone construction in batch files performing pretty huge number of various tasks. Btw, there's one more way to cope with the task by using a subroutine, i.e. `for /f %%s in ('set') do call :DoSmth "%%s" \r\n ... \r\n :DoSmth \r\n set var=%1 \r\n echo %var:~1,3%`

Comment: @Phate01, don't use `%date%` to construct a date in a certain format. The format is specific to the user's culture and may change. Use WMI instead to get date and time in a useful format that doesn't depend on the user's settings. Also I'm not sure what this comment is doing here, as this question was not about date or time.

Comment: Actually you're right as I guess I wanted to comment a different question :)

Comment: **`%var is base 0`** this is implicitly only :( derived from the second sample.

Comment: @Fr0sT It does work, yes, but you have to use `setlocal ` and enable delayed expansion.

Comment: @user2262111 isn't that what I said in comment from  Apr 28 '14 ?

Comment: How to use `~othervar` in place of `~10`? It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 43):

Nicely explained above!

For all those who may suffer like me to get this working in a localized Windows (mine is XP in Slovak), you may try to replace the `%` with a `!`

So:

```
SET TEXT=Hello World
SET SUBSTRING=!TEXT:~3,5!
ECHO !SUBSTRING!
```

Comment: Note this will work only after `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` command

Comment: try `SET TEXT="<Hello World>"` ,  `SET SUBSTRING=!TEXT:~1,-1!`  or `SET SUBSTRING=%TEXT:~1,-1%` , `ECHO !SUBSTRING!` or `ECHO %SUBSTRING%`

Comment: How to use `~othervar` in place of `~3`? It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 14):

As an additional info to Joey's answer, which isn't described in the help of `set /?` nor `for /?`.

`%~0` expands to the name of the own batch, exactly as it was typed.
So if you start your batch it will be expanded as

```
%~0   - mYbAtCh
%~n0  - mybatch
%~nx0 - mybatch.bat
```

But there is one exception, expanding in a subroutine could fail

```
echo main- %~0
call :myFunction
exit /b

:myFunction
echo func - %~0
echo func - %~n0
exit /b
```

This results to

```
main - myBatch
Func - :myFunction
func - mybatch
```

**In a function `%~0` expands always to the name of the function, not of the batch file.**
But if you use at least one modifier it will show the filename again!

Answer (score 1):

**How to do a substring within a batch file?**
This version takes the start end length of the string as variables.
So it enables you to do a substring dynamically (e. g. in Loops).

```
@echo off
set sLongString=MyVeryLongString
call :Substring %sLongString% 2 8 sSubStrResult
echo %sSubStrResult%
```

Output: `VeryLong`

**And here comes the necessary function:**

```
REM ### Substring(sLongString, iStart, iCharCount): sSubStrResult
REM ### =========================================================
REM ### Example:
REM ###   set sLongString=MyVeryLongString
REM ###   call :Substring %sLongString% 2 8 sSubStrResult
REM ###   echo %sSubStrResult%
REM ### Output: VeryLong
REM ### Michael Hutter / Dez 2023
:Substring
SET sLongStr=%1
SET iFirstChar=%2
SET iCharCount=%3
CALL SET sSubStr=%%sLongStr:~%iFirstChar%,%iCharCount%%%
(endlocal & set %4=%sSubStr%)
goto :eof
```