# Recursively delete all folders starting with

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion, command-line, directory

I need to write a command in a .bat file that recursively deletes all the folders starting with a certain string. How may I achieve this ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is the complete answer you are looking for:

```
FOR /D /R %%X IN (certain_string*) DO RD /S /Q "%%X"
```

where obviously you need to replace `certain_string` with the string your folders start with.

This deletes **RECURSIVELY** as you asked (I mean it goes throught all folders and subfolders).

Comment: Nothing other than @Maorco's answer worked for me. Sadly he has not got any votes other than mine. :(

Comment: Thx. I had to exclude two directories, which resulted in this command: `FOR /D /R %%X IN (*.lproj) DO IF /I "%%~xnX" neq "en.lproj" IF /I "%%~xnX" neq "english.lproj" RD /S /Q "%%~fX"`. Explanation: [`%%~xnX`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/636391) equals the full directory name. `IF /I .. neq "en.lproj"` filters all directories which are equal to `"en.lproj"` (`/I` = case-insensitive). IFs [can be nested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2143203). In the end, I've recursively deleted all directories ending with `.lproj`, except for `en.lproj` and `english.lproj`.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
for /d %a in (certain_string*) do rd /s %a
```

This will work from the command prompt. Inside a batch file, you would have to double the `%`s, as usual:

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in (certain_string*) do rd /s %%a
```

Comment: Ouch. I need more sleep ... or tea ... *(hits head on the table)*

Comment: Hmm, although that probably won't recurse into the dir tree and find deeper folders matching the criteria, right? (My solutions don't do that as well, but I just realized that's what the OP meant).

Comment: I had to expand this a bit from my original simple attempt, because `rd` doesn't appear to expand wildcards by itself.

Comment: To recursively look for directories starting with a prefix, you may be able to use `for /r` or some combination thereof.

Comment: Oh, not nice. I didn't try it either since I currently have no directories lying around to wreck :-)

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: did this work? It doesn't work when trying to delete directories ending with ".delme", I tried your suggestion like this: `for /d %%x in (*.delme) do rd /s /q "%%x"` but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfinished, I think. If you meant "Recursively go down a directory hierarchy to delete all folders starting with a certain string", then the following might suffice:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b /ad abc*') do rd /s /q "%%x"
```

This will recurse into the directory tree, finding all folders starting with "abc", iterate over that list and removing each folder.

Maybe you need to wrap an `if exist` around the `rd` depending on the order in which directories are found and returned. In general, iterating over something and changing it at the same time is rarely a good idea but sometimes it works :-)

Comment: Rössel: did this work? It doesn't work when trying to delete directories ending with ".delme", I tried your suggestion like this: for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b /ad *.delme') do rd /s /q "%%x" BUT IT DOES NOT SEEM TO WORK.

Comment: @Marco: No need to shout. If in doubt, ask a new question and tell your problems clearly and in detail. Something like »Doesn't work« is usually a bad issue report.

Comment: Rossel: wasn't shouting, I just wrote upper case. I'll ask new question then.

Answer (score 0):

rm -rf -- "Directory name"

Ex : rm -rf -- "-2096378"

Above command will deletes the folders/directories starting with - or wildcard characters

Answer (score -1):

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %i IN ('DIR **[[SearchTerm]]** /A:D /s /b') do rd /S / Q %i
```