# How to make a OR statement in a batch file?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, sqlcmd

Hi want to exclude 2 or more files from my batch file.

My batch file executes all `SQL` files in that folder.

Here is the code:

```
ECHO %USERNAME% started the batch process at %TIME% >output.txt 

FOR %%G IN (*.sql) DO (
//IF would go here to skip unwanted files
sqlcmd.exe  -S RMSDEV7 -E   -d ChaseDataMedia7 -i "%%G" >>output.txt
)

pause
```

So, how would i add and if statemant to skip the files in the loop that i don't want to execute?

Comment: Q&D but another option might be to rename both files before your loop and restore them afterwards.

Comment: @Lieven Viable, but i don't want to delete and restore 20 times a day, and want the other developers to just run the batch file. No need to worry about delete and restores.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logical operators ("and", "or") in DOS batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143187/logical-operators-and-or-in-dos-batch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chain IFs;

```
FOR %%G IN (*.sql) DO (
   if not %%G==foo.sql if not %%G==bar.sql (
      some command "%%G"
   )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set unwantedFiles=foo bar baz
for %%g in (*.sql) do (
   set "test=!unwantedFiles:%%~Ng=!"
   if "!test!" == "!unwantedFiles!" (
      echo %%~Ng.sql is not unwanted, process it:
      echo Process with %%g
   )
)
```

Take a name and copy unwantedFiles by removing current name. If the result is the same as before, this name is NOT in unwantedFiles, so process it...