# Batch FOR Loop Fail

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, imagemagick-convert

I have been scouring SO and Google search results for almost a week now, trying to make a simple batch script work. I think my problem arises from a lack of understanding Batch FOR loops and DelayedExpansion.

*There's a huge amount of related questions and answers on this topic, but not a single one of the posts I have seen is able to break down the information in a way that makes sense to me*.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET /a QUALITY=20
SET /a STEP=5
:loop    
convert input.jpg -resize 1080x1080 -quality %quality% -strip ./1080/output.jpg
SET /a quality+=step
for %%G in (./1080/output.jpg) DO (
    set filesize=%%~zG
    if !filesize! LSS 100000 if !quality! LSS 100 goto loop
)
```

The intent of this code is to **convert** (ImageMagick) an image with an initial compression quality of 20, check the filesize, and start over with a slightly higher quality setting each iteration **while** the filesize is less than 100KB AND the quality is less than 100.

As it is, the output is such:

```
>SET /a QUALITY=20
>SET /a STEP=5
>convert input.jpg -resize 1080x1080 -quality 20 -strip ./1080/output.jpg
>SET /a quality+=step
>for %G in (./1080/output.jpg) DO (
>set filesize=%~zG
>if !filesize! LSS 100000 if !quality! LSS 100 goto loop
>(
>set filesize=
>if !filesize! LSS 100000 if !quality! LSS 100 goto loop
>)
>convert export.jpg -resize 1080x1080 -quality 25 -strip ./1080/output.jpg
```

... etc (**infinite loop**). This loops until killed.

The output.jpg in this particular test run (quality at 20) has a filesize of 82.3KB, which is less than the 100KB threshold and should therefore 'goto loop' and generate an output.jpg (quality at 25) with a filesize of 96.4KB, 'goto loop', and generate a final output.jpg (quality at 30) with a filesize of 109KB.

*I believe that the desired output should be something like this:*

```
>SET /a QUALITY=20
>SET /a STEP=5
>convert input.jpg -resize 1080x1080 -quality 20 -strip ./1080/output.jpg
>SET /a quality+=step
>SET filesize=82300
>if 82300 LSS 100000 if 20 LSS 100 goto loop
>convert input.jpg -resize 1080x1080 -quality 25 -strip ./1080/output.jpg
>SET /a quality+=step
>SET filesize=96400
>if 96400 LSS 100000 if 25 LSS 100 goto loop
>convert input.jpg -resize 1080x1080 -quality 30 strip ./1080/output.jpb
>SET /a quality+=step
>SET filesize=109000
>if 109000 LSS 100000 if 30 LSS 100 goto loop
>
```

---

**EDIT:** I've tried implementing suggestions from David Ruhmann and Mike Nakis, and also an OR trick from [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143187/logical-operators-and-or-in-dos-batch). Unfortunately, the resulting code seems to have the same problem as before, and I am left with an infinite loop (incrementing in quality each time).

```
SET /a QUALITY=30
SET /a STEP=5
md large
:loop
convert export.jpg -resize 1080x1080 -quality %quality% -strip ./large/xhdpi.jpg
@set res=true
@echo Quality = %quality%
@SET /a quality+=step
@for %%G in (./large/xhdpi*) DO (if %%~zG GTR 100000 set res=false)
@for %%G in (./large/xhdpi*) DO (if !quality! GTR 100 set res=false)
@if "%res%"=="false" exit /b
@if "%res%"=="true" goto loop
```

---

It would seem that the true issue at fault in my code is that %%~zG is not being assigned a value. **Why is %%G returning an empty string?**

Comment: You are not closing the parentheses scope of your for loop so it does not know where to end processing the loop and instead does nothing. `)`

Comment: Also Delayed Expansion should not be needed if you remove the set filesize, replace `!filesize!` in the if statement with `%%~zG`, and change `!quality!` to `%quality%`  Then the for statement will be one line `for %%G in (./1080/output.jpg) DO if %%~zG LSS 100000 if %quality% LSS 100 goto loop`

Comment: Whoops, thanks for catching that. Fixing that error has now caused an infinite loop. I will edit the question to reflect the change.

Comment: Thanks for your responses @david Your second comment resulted in the 100KB/100% threshold from stopping the loop, but the size variable is not given any value. Output is as follows:
`>if  LSS 100000 if 100 LSS 100 goto loop`

Comment: I see echoed `set filesize=%zG` in your _output_ example: missing `~` modifier.

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks. Edited to fix the typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
:loop    
convert input.jpg -resize 1080x1080 -quality %quality% -strip ./1080/output.jpg
SET /a quality+=step
for %%G in (./1080/output.jpg) DO set filesize=%%~zG
if !filesize! LSS 100000 if !quality! LSS 100 goto loop
```

Disclaimer: I am unable to test this, so it is quite possible that I have made a mistake, (I have never even seen `LSS` before,) but this should give you an idea of what you have done wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Looks like everything works except that it won't **stop** working. It loops indefinitely, incrementing -quality by 5 (it was set to 135 when I killed it).

Comment: Try "if filesize above max exit loop" followed by "if quality above max exit loop" followed by an unconditional "goto loop".  ("exit loop" would be implemented as a goto a label further down, or simply as an exit from the batch file.)

Comment: In any case, that's a different problem.  This question was about the batch file not looping, which has now been fixed, right?  So you owe me at least an upvote!  C-:=

Answer (score 1):

I simulated your routine by `type`ing a 12K file **qotn.txt** to append to the ".jpg" using this routine:

```dos
@ECHO Off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET "filename=u:/sourcedir/1080-output.jpg"
TYPE qotn.txt >"%filename%"
SET /a QUALITY=20
SET /a STEP=5
:loop    
TYPE qotn.txt >>"%filename%"
:: convert input.jpg -resize 1080x1080 -quality %quality% -strip ./1080/output.jpg
SET /a quality+=step
for %%G in (%filename%) DO (
    set filesize=%%~zG
    if !filesize! LSS 100000 if !quality! LSS 100 goto loop
)
DIR/d u:\sourcedir
SET q

GOTO :EOF
```

...and it worked perfectly.

So all I can contribute are a few comments - yeah, not strictly an "answer" but not easy to massage into a "commment"...soz.

Directory-separators are `\` not `/` which is used for switches. It appears to work, but for my preference, I'd use the `\`. Note that at the end, I used `DIR` of the destination directory - because `dir` doesn't like `%filename%` (contains `/`)

The `for %%G` would not execute the set/if if the file does not exist. Therefore the file is found, regardless of the `/`vs`\` issue.

The real issue is why `filesize` is not being set to the size of the target as demonstrated by the line `>set filesize=` in the run-report.

There appears to be no reason for `delayedexpansion`. Since `quality` does not change within the `for` loop, `%quality%` can be used and `%%~zG` can be used instead of `!filesize!` in the `if` statement.

Note that you are changing `quality` after running `convert`, so `quality` as seen by the for`loop is not the quality use by`convert`. This won't impact the size problem, but it will limit`quality` actually used to 95%.

So - I'd suspect that the mmetavariable `%%G` in use is in a different case within the loop - but the run report says otherwise. I even tried inserting a space between the `$$~z` and `G` - but that gave different results, not an infinite loop.

Favourited pending a resolution...

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "inputFile=.\input.jpg"
    set "outputFile=.\1080\output.jpg"

    set "done="
    type nul > "%outputFile%"
    for /l %%q in (20 5 100) do if not defined done for %%o in ("%outputFile%") do (
        if %%~zo LSS 100000 (
            convert "%inputFile%" -resize 1080x1080 -quality %%q -strip "%outputFile%"
        ) else set "done=1"
    )
```

Instead of jumping back for each iteration, this code just uses a `for /l` to iterate over the available quality options. A variable is used to determine if the loop should continue converting the file, but can be replaced with a `goto` to jump out of the loop.