# convert sh file to bat file, existance of directories

Tags: bash, batch-file

I would like to convert this code from sh file to .bat file, how can i do?

```
 # Validate  directories
if [ ! -d "$DIRA" -o \
    ! -d "$DIRB" -o \
        ! -d "$DIRC" ]
then
    echo " invalid  path"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: [Microsoft docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/65994)

Comment: @Thomas thanks, but in my sample there is if condition with more than one condition

Comment: That is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143187/logical-operators-and-or-in-dos-batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be written like this in .bat file:

```
rem validate directories
set VALID_PATH=true
IF NOT EXIST %DIRA%\NUL set VALID_PATH=false
IF NOT EXIST %DIRB%\NUL set VALID_PATH=false
IF NOT EXIST %DIRC%\NUL set VALID_PATH=false
if %VALID_PATH%==false (
echo invalid path
goto done 
)
```