# How to use IF command in CMD to check matching criteria on multiple variables?

Tags: cmd

I'm kinda newbie to CMD. I was wondering; is it possible to check for multiple criteria on different variables at once, using IF command? I mean, what would be the syntax of IF command if you wanted to check  2 different variables at the same time matching the given criteria? 
I mean does that thing exist? Something like:

**IF %%variable1%% == variableone AND %variable2% == variabletwo do stuff**

I've been trying to sort this out myself, but couldn't find a way to to doit. Kept getting errors. Maybe there's something wrong in the syntax of the command or I'm missing something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logical operators ("and", "or") in DOS batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143187/logical-operators-and-or-in-dos-batch)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use logical operators, but you can do this:

```
IF %%variable1%% == variableone IF %variable2% == variabletwo GOTO :DOSTUFF
```

or

```
IF %%variable1%% == variableone (
  IF %variable2% == variabletwo (
    rem do stuff here
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to implement a logical AND:

```
if "%variable1%@%variable2%" == "variableone@variabletwo" goto :dostuff
```

Note1: `@` is just a delimiter to get sure `foo`+`bar` and `foob`+`ar` are not treated the same. (`foo@bar` vs. `foob@ar`) Without a delimiter, both would give `foobar`.

Note2: the quotes prevent a syntax error when one side of the comparison is empty

Note3: I assume, `%%variable1%%` is a typing error and should read `%variable1%`