# batch file less than and greater than?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get a batch file to test if a number is between two numbers but it is only checking for the first number. I am using the "and" operator but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's the code:

```
REM Used to keep variable for duration of script
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cls
@echo off 

echo Math Experts Commands
set /p loop=Loop how many times: 

for /L %%A IN (1,1,!loop!) DO (
    REM Request the first number
    echo Enter your first digit you wish to add

    REM Set first user input to "num1"
    set /p num1=

    REM Request the second number
    echo Enter the second digit you wish to add the first by

    REM Set second usr input to "num2"
    set /p num2=

    REM Add the 2 values then set the outcome to "total"
    set /a total=num1+num2

    REM Clear the screen
    cls

    if !total! leq 4 (
    echo ####################################################################################
    echo #    Hosts Req:      #      Mask:      #      Netmask:      #      Max Supported:  #                                                  
    echo #    !total!                      /30           255.255.255.252                4         #
    echo ####################################################################################
    echo.
    ) else if !total! gtr 4 and leq 8 (   REM <----WHERE THE PROBLEM IS. 
    echo ####################################################################################
    echo #    Hosts Req:      #      Mask:      #      Netmask:      #      Max Supported:  #                                                  
    echo #    !total!                      /29            255.255.255.248               8        #
    echo ####################################################################################
    echo. 
    )
    )

    REM Pause the console
    pause
    echo.
)
```

Comment: @jbiWeisendorf  I've tried that as well and it says "&& was unexpected at this time" when i run it.

Comment: my comment was false :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical `and` operator don't exist in BAT,

You have to make a second `if` test against you variable :

```
else (if !total! gtr 4 if !total! leq 8 (....))
```

**EDIT :**

```
 else (
     if !total! gtr 4 if !total! leq 8 (echo between 4 and 8)
     if !total! gtr 16 if !total! leq 32 (echo between 16 and 32)
     )
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked but now i face a new problem in that i need to do the same thing a few more times with increasing numbers. (ex. >8 & <=16, >16 & <=32, ect.)

Comment: @Brett - Your options are copy/pasting a whole lot or figuring out the math needed to dynamically fill in a template.

Comment: Thank you so much, It Worked! I've been working on this for hours and this might be the only thing i did't try

Answer (score 1):

See...Chaining IF commands (AND).
https://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Here is an implementation for AND/OR/XOR/NOT operators in an IF statement by Prof. Timo Salmi   
http://www.netikka.net/tsneti/info/tscmd120.htm

Another good thread
[Logical operators ("and", "or") in DOS batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143187/logical-operators-and-or-in-dos-batch)

Comment: Please include appropriate content from those websites to answer the question rather than just linking. Other websites may go away, making them no longer useful as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
:: I used code from here; http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_booleanlogic.php
:: Requirements
:: Test for x >8 & <=16, >16 & <=32, etc
:: I only implemented the first two tests
:: A loop could condense the code maybe?
::
:: Reference: IF statement logical operators
:: EQU : Equal
:: NEQ : Not equal

:: LSS : Less than <
:: LEQ : Less than or Equal <=

:: GTR : Greater than >
:: GEQ : Greater than or equal >=

:: Initialize Variables
set Comp1=0
set Comp2=0

:: Set a test case
set X=18
echo x=%x%
echo.

:: Test "8 < x <= 16"
IF %x% GTR 8 (SET Cond1=1) ELSE (SET Cond1=0)
IF %x% LEQ 16 (SET Cond2=1) ELSE (SET Cond2=0)
SET /A "ResultAND = %Cond1% & %Cond2%"
IF %ResultAND% EQU 1 (SET Comp1=1) ELSE (SET Comp1=0)
IF %Comp1% EQU 1 (ECHO %x% is between 9 and 16) ELSE (ECHO %x% is NOT between 9 and 16)

:: Test "8 < x <= 16 OR 16 < x <= 32"
IF %x% GTR 16 (SET Cond1=1) ELSE (SET Cond1=0)
IF %x% LEQ 32 (SET Cond2=1) ELSE (SET Cond2=0)
SET /A "ResultAND = %Cond1% & %Cond2%"
IF %ResultAND% EQU 1 (SET Comp2=1) ELSE (SET Comp2=0)
IF %Comp2% EQU 1 (ECHO %x% is between 17 and 32) ELSE (ECHO %x% is NOT between 17 and 32)

SET /A "ResultOR = %Comp1% | %Comp2%"
IF %ResultOR% EQU 1 (ECHO %x% is between 9 and 16 OR between 17 and 32) ELSE (ECHO %x% is NOT between 9 and 16 OR between 17 and 32)

:: Logical Operator Tests
::SET /A "ResultAND = %Cond1% & %Cond2%"
::IF %ResultAND% EQU 1 (ECHO AND: TRUE) ELSE (ECHO AND: FALSE)

::SET /A "ResultOR = %Cond1% | %Cond2%"
::IF %ResultOR% EQU 1 (ECHO OR:  TRUE) ELSE (ECHO OR:  FALSE)

::SET /A "ResultXOR = %Cond1% ˆ %Cond2%"
::IF %ResultXOR% EQU 1 (ECHO XOR: TRUE) ELSE (ECHO XOR: FALSE)

pause
```