# How to make a random chance "function" in Batch

Tags: batch-file, random

I'm making a small little game I want a random chance to get certain items (e.g. if the random number is greater than 10 but less than 15 then you will get a certain item). Here's what I've already tried which resulted in a crash.

```
    set /a chance= %random% %%30+1
if %chance% gtr 10 && lss 30 (
    set /a %nails%+1
    echo You got nails! %chance%
    )
```

This piece right here was just a test, but should give you an idea of what I am going for. This is really the only way I can think of doing it. If you could help, please do! :)

Comment: "resulted in a crash" is not a very useful bug report. A useful bug report always has (1) the mimimal code that shows the problem, (2) the expected behaviour, and (3) the actual behaviour.

Comment: Well, when I run that part of the code it crashes. I don't know the problem (hence why I'm here), I told you the expected behavior, and the actual behavior is the crash, so I don't exactly know what you wanted me to tell you. Batch doesn't exactly tell you what's wrong all the time.

Comment: For example: What gets output to the screen, if anything? Does the cmd window shut down? Does the machine reboot? Doe it just sit there, seemingly doing nothing, but with no prompt? Answers to any of those would be better than "it crashed".

Comment: What is `set /a %nails%+1` supposed to do? do you mean `set /A nails+=1`?

Comment: The `IF` command has invalid syntax. If you are running this from the command prompt you should see that when it is executing with ECHO ON.  The double ampersand is NOT and AND condition for the `IF` command.  The double ampersand is conditional execution for the next command that it needs to execute if the previous command was successful. If the condition is true it tries to execute the double ampersand as a command which is not a valid executable. The error you get from your code is `&& was unexpected at this time.`

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of problems in that code:

```
set /a chance= %random% %%30+1
if %chance% gtr 10 && lss 30 (
    set /a %nails%+1
    echo You got nails! %chance%
)
```

Going through them:

- The `if` statement is not valid, `&&` is the "execute next command if previous command worked" conjunction, not a general "and" operator. To do what you want would be:
  `if %chance% gtr 10 if %chance% lss 30`.
  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143187/logical-operators-and-or-in-dos-batch/2143396#2143396) for a way to do `and` and `or` in `cmd` language.
- The command `set /a %nails%+1` does not actually *change* `nails` in any way, it just evaluates an expression and throws it away. You need an *assignment* to assign a value, and you don't need the variable markers in this case:
  `set /a "nails += 1"`.
- If you're using `delayedexpansion` to print out `nails` (and you should be), you need a `!` both before and after the variable name:
  `echo You got !nails! %chance%`.

> As an aside, you'll probably notice I have a penchant for quoting my `set /a` expressions and spacing them nicely - I find this aids readability.

---

That will fix some specific problems but, to be honest, you're probably better off making a *generic* function that can give you a yes/no answer for some probability of an event happening. That way, you can reuse it anywhere you need it.

You can use a function like `chance`, shown below in a complete program, to decide whether something should happen based on a percentage:

```
@echo off
goto :main

:chance
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set retcode=1==0
    set /a "value = %random% %% 100"
    rem echo %value% rem uncomment for debugging
    if %value% lss %2 set retcode=1==1
    endlocal && set %1=%retcode%
    goto :eof

:main
    call :chance result 50
    echo %result%
```

It should be called with both a variable name to put the result into, and the percentage level you want to use. For example, if you wanted to set a variable `hasdied` based on a 5% chance, you would call it with:

```
call :chance hasdied 5
if %hasdied% goto :handlebeingdead
```

The function contains a number of features which probably bear explanation:

- The `setlocal` command ensures that no variables *escape* the scope of this function (but see below), useful for proper encapsulation.
- The `value` variable is set to some random value between `0` and `99` inclusive. It's not perfectly distributed since `%random%` will give you a value up to `32767` so will be slightly skewed toward numbers less than `68`. Said skew is probably not enough to concern yourself with.
- This value is then compared with the threshold you provided (the second argument) to decide the return value true or false.
- The return value is rather sneaky in that it gives you an *expression* that you can put into an `if` statement without having to do an explicit comparison like:
  `if %hasdied%==1`
  By returning such an equality comparison directly, you can just use the return value as if it was boolean.
- The `endlocal` then cleans up any variable changes that have been made in this function, *including* the return code. However, the fact that the substitutions on this line take place *before* any of it is executed means that the `set` part of it will already have the correct value of `retcode` substituted before the `endlocal` cleans it up. This is a way to have specific variables "escape" the scope bounded by `setlocal/endlocal`. The `retcode` value is therefor placed in the parameter whose name you provided as the first argument.
- The `set %1=` part of that command is a way to allow you to specify what variable should receive the value in the call itself, akin to `myvar = function()`. That stops you from having to allocate a hard-coded variable name to each function and then assign it to another variable after the call.
- And, of course, the `goto :eof` is simply a `return` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the && does not exist in batch. Nested if statements work:

```
set /a chance= %random% %%30+1
echo %chance%
IF %chance% GTR 10 (IF %chance% LSS 15 (
     echo You got nails! %chance%
))
```

Comment: @bar9833625 `&&` really do exist in batch, is the successful operator, and `||` not success, as in `somecommand  && echo succeded || echo failed`

Comment: @elzooilogico: careful with that, it doesn't always behave as expected (as an `if/then/else`): `xx && echo yes || echo no` appears to work, outputting `no` after complaining about `xx`. `dir && echo yes || echo no` appears to work, outputting `yes` after the directory. However, `dir && xx || echo no` outputs `no` after the directory, despite the fact that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `&&` like that. You need to run the if statement twice to match both `gtr` and `lss` you can put them one after the other:

```
@echo off
set /a chance=%random% %%30+1
if %chance% gtr 10 if %chance% lss 30 (
    set /a nails+=1
    echo You got nails! %chance%
 )
```

Also note the correct way of increasing a variable `set /a nails+=1`

Answer (score 0):

the if condition approach works and all, but is somewhat clunky if your going to be scripting in many loot situations. it is by far easier to use an array setup with a macro that can access ranges within the array to allow you to simply and easily script loot boxes that roll different items by using substring modification to change the index of the array the random number can access. a demonstration:

```bat
@Echo off
:new
::: -------------------------------------------------------------------||    MACRO DEFINITIONS
Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
(Set \n=^^^
%=DNR=%
)
rem  *********************  Display any existing character names for continuation or deletion of characters
If Exist "%TEMP%\%~n0_*_save.bat" (Echo/Your Characters:&Echo/&(For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('Dir "%TEMP%\%~n0_*_save.bat" /B')Do For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=_" %%o in ("%%~nG") Do  < Nul Set /P "=[%%o] ")&Echo/)
:character
Set /P "Name=Name: "
If Exist "%TEMP%\%~n0_%Name%_save.bat" (Echo/[C]ontinue / [D]elete?&For /F "Delims=" %%O in ('Choice /N /C:cd')Do If /I "%%O"=="C" (Goto :playon)Else (Del /P "%TEMP%\%~n0_%Name%_save.bat" & Goto :character))
If "%Name%"=="" Goto :character
:playon
rem ***  Inventory Macro. Displays all elements for the given group and their current values.
rem :::  Usage: %INV:@=$varname[%
    Set "INV=Echo/&(For /F "Tokens=2 Delims==" %%i in ('Set @') Do (Set "VN=%%i"&^< Nul Set /P"=[!VN:$=!:!%%i!] "))&Echo/"
rem ***  Autosave macro. Can be incorperated into other macro's
rem :::  Usage: %Save%
    Set SAVE=(For /F "Tokens=1 Delims==" %%i in ('Set $') Do (If not "!%%i!"=="" Echo/Set "%%i=!%%i!"))^>"%TEMP%\%~n0_!name!_save.bat"
rem ***  Location Display Macro with autosave macro included
rem :::  Usage: %Loc:@=LocationLABEL%
    Set "Loc=(Set "$Loc=@"&Title !$Loc:_= !)&%Save%"
rem ***  Loot box Macro to generate random loot from specified range of an indexed array
rem ***  !random! %%4 + Index# will access an index range between the index # and 4 above the index number.
rem :::  Usage: %Loot:@=index#%
    Set "LOOT=(For /F "UsebackQ Delims=" %%i in (`"Set /A i#=!Random! %%4 + @"`) Do For /F "UsebackQ Delims=" %%v in (`"Set /A v#=!Random! %%3 + 1"`) Do (Set "VN=!$Loot[%%i]:$=!"&Echo/You got %%v !VN!&Set /A "!$Loot[%%i]!+=%%v")) 2> Nul & %SAVE%"
rem ***  the below  macros /I /V and /P are not used in this example. - They are an optional method for defining
rem ***  variables prefixed with $ that automatically saves them for reloading
rem :::  usage: %/I:V=Varname%Input Prompt String:
Set "/I=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 (Set /P "$V=!$PromptStr:$=!: "&%Save%)Else Set $PromptStr="
rem :::  usage: %/P:V=Varname%VariableValue
Set "/V=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 (Set "$V=!str!"&%Save%)Else Set str="
rem :::  usage: %/A:V=Varname%=Equation
Set "/A=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 (Set /A "$V!sum!"&%Save%)Else Set sum="
rem *** Wait prompt Macro
rem :::  usage: %Wait:#=Integer value for time in seconds%Wait Prompt String
Set "Wait=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 (Timeout # /Nobreak > Nul & (Pause | Echo/!Output!) 2> Nul )Else Set Output="
rem ***  Array definition macro. Asigns the element names to an indexed Groupname (Array), With each element being assigned an initial 0 value
Rem :::  Usage: %DefArray%{VarGroupName}{Element names as list}
Set DefArray=For %%n in (1 2) Do if %%n==2 (%\n%
 Set "i#=0"%\n%
 For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims={}" %%G in ("!List!") Do (%\n%
  For %%i in (%%~H) Do (%\n%
   Set "$%%~G[!i#!]=$%%i"%\n%
   Set "$%%i=0"%\n%
   Set /A i#+=1 ^> Nul%\n%
  )%\n%
 )%\n%
) Else Set List=
Set Menu=CLS^&Set "Copt="^&For %%n in (1 2) Do if %%n==2 (%\n%
 Echo/[E]xit%\n%
 For %%G in (!OPTS!)Do (%\n%
  Set "opt=@%%~G"%\n%
  Set "opt=!opt:_= !"^&Set "Opt=!Opt:~,-1!"%\n%
  Set "Copt=!Copt!%%~G"%\n%
  Echo/!Opt! [%%~G]%\n%
 )%\n%
 (For /F "Delims=" %%O in ('Choice /N /C !Copt!E')Do If "%%O"=="E" (Endlocal^&Endlocal^&Set "Name="^&Goto :New) Else (CLS^&Goto :@%%O))%\n%
) Else Set OPTS=
::: -------------------------------------------------------------------||    END MACRO DEFINITIONS

::: -------------------------------------------------------------------||    Example Script
REM // required to be enabled PRIOR to macro Use, AFTER definition.
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 %DefArray%{Loot}{Wood Nails Ore Leather Gold Silver Bronze Jade}
 IF Exist "%TEMP%\%~n0_!name!_save.bat" (
  Call "%TEMP%\%~n0_!name!_save.bat"
  Goto :!$Loc!
 )
:Menu
 %Loc:@=Menu%
 %Menu:@=Loot_Box_% "1" "2"
Goto :Menu
:Loot_Box_1
 %Loc:@=Loot_Box_1%
 %Loot:@=0%
 %INV:@=$Loot[%
 %Wait:#=1%
Goto :Menu
:Loot_Box_2
 %Loc:@=Loot_Box_2%
 %Loot:@=4%
 %INV:@=$Loot[%
 %Wait:#=1%Demo wait prompt
Goto :Menu
```