# Is it possible to have an if then command check for multiple variables, instead of just one

Tags: batch-file

Essentially, can you achieve this:

```
if %num1% == 1 echo hi
if %num1% == 5 echo hi
if %num1% == 9 echo hi
```

In a simpler way such as:

```
if %num1% == 1,5,9 echo hi
```

edit: maybe made my intentions more clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logical operators ("and", "or") in DOS batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143187/logical-operators-and-or-in-dos-batch)

Comment: @JohnWu Not really. Perhaps I miss understood but this seems more like a range between different numbers, like anything between 1-5. I may have been unclear but I want something that would have numbers that don't fit on a range. Like 1, 3, 6, 8.

Comment: Try `for %%a in (1 5 9) do if %num1%==%%a echo hi` (use single percents `%a` if at the cmd prompt instead of a batch file).

Comment: @dxiv Yes this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dxiv did the following:

```
for %%a in (1 5 9) do if %num1%==%%a echo hi
```

This works well for using if then for specific numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Use variable expansion find/replace to test if a value is embedded within a test variable. If the result does not match the original test value, then a relevant value was found.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "test= 1 5 9 "
if !test: %num% =! neq !test! echo Hi
```

The leading and trailing spaces in test and also around `%num%` are critical if you might be dealing with numbers >= 10.

Not relevant to number searches, but this technique is not case sensitive - it cannot differentiate between upper and lower case.

Answer (score 1):

You can also test dynamically using substring modification within a macro such as:

```bat
@Echo off
Set "list=,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,"
Set "num[1]=1"
Set "num[2]=5"
Set "num[3]=9"

Set "CompVal=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 (For %%v in (!cVal!)Do (Set "compare=!Var:,%%~v,=,!" & If not "!compare!" == "!Var!" (Echo/%%~v is in Var)Else (Echo/%%~v not found)))Else Set cVal="
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem /* usage examples */
rem /* Search for matching list elements from an array */
 For /F "Tokens=2 Delims==" %%i in ('Set num[')Do %CompVal:Var=list%%%i
rem /* Search a defined list var for specific integers */
 %CompVal:Var=list%13;2;22;305
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method that inverts the conditions and skips `echo hi` in case all of them are true:

```cmd
if not %num1% == 1 if not %num1% == 5 if not %num1% == 9 goto :SKIP
echo hi
:SKIP
```

The operator `==` forces string comparison, so avoid it to permit numeric comparisons:

```cmd
if %num1% neq 1 if %num1% neq 5 if %num1% neq 9 goto :SKIP
echo hi
:SKIP
```

---

Another method is to use an interim flag-like variable:

```cmd
set "SKIP="
if %num1% neq 1 if %num1% neq 5 if %num1% neq 9 set "SKIP=#"
if not defined SKIP echo hi
```