# Windows batch file to delete folders/subfolders using wildcards

Tags: batch-file, directory

I need to delete all folders in "tomin" folder, which name contains terminates with the ".delme" string.
The deletion need to be done recurively: I mean on all directory and SUB directories.

I though to do this:

```
FOR /R tomin %%X IN (*.delme) DO (RD /S /Q "%%X")
```

but it does not work, I think /R ignores wildcards.

Before asking this question I searched also in SO and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807425/batch-recursively-delete-all-folders-starting-with): but the answers did not help me in solving my issue, following the suggestion given there I tried:

```
FOR /F tomin "delims=" %%X IN ('dir /b /ad *.delme') DO RD /S /Q "%%X"
```

But it did not work either.

Comment: Can you please post your full code to delete files. I am totally new to batch files. and I wan to delete all folder named as ".sass-cache" with all it's containts from all  subfolders.

Comment: @SaurabhBayani: `FOR /D /R yourfolder %%X IN .sass-cache DO RD /S /Q "%%X"` Deletes all files and folders that finds into `yourfolder` and named `.sass-cache`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your first command would work, but you forgot the `/D` to specify that you want directories.

`FOR /D /R tomin %%X IN (*.delme) DO RD /S /Q "%%X"`

Should do the trick.