# DOS batch: get last folder from relative path

Tags: parsing, substring, extract, batch-file, indexof

I have the following values in a DOS batch file (for example...):

```
..\Apple\Jones  
..\Banana\Smith  
..\Pear\Wilson
```

I need to extract the last name values ("Jones", "Smith", "Wilson") from each value.  What one technique can I use that will always give me these substring values?

Comment: [Windows cmd is **not** DOS](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). DOS has no ability like `%~n0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this topic : [What is the best way to do a substring in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636381/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-substring-in-a-batch-file)

I suggest you to use

```
%~n0
```

Comment: I don't follow.  That shows me the name of the batch file?  How does that give me for what the question asks?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. %0 contains the path to your script. With %~n0 you extract the script name only. Here is a more explicit exemple :  for /D %%i in ("..\Apple\Jones","..\Banana\Smith","..\Pear\Wilson") do echo %%~ni

Comment: Delightful. Thank you.  Note: I used echo %%~ni%%~xi, as my last folder (the real data) is a directory whose name includes a period.

Comment: `%%~ni%%~xi` can be written as `%%~nxi`

Answer (score -1):

I already wrote a function for that. You give it any path and it returns you only it's filename or pathname. Works for any path: Url, Windows path, Unix path, etc...

Copy this function at the end of your batch script: (Instructions below)

```
rem ===========================================================================

:Name_From_Path
SetLocal

set _TMP_FOLDERNAME=%1
for %%g in ("%_TMP_FOLDERNAME%") do set _TMP_FOLDERNAME=%%~nxg

EndLocal & set _Name_From_Path=%_TMP_FOLDERNAME%
goto :EOF

rem ===========================================================================
```

Usage:

```
CALL :Name_Of_Path ..\Apple\Jones
ECHO %_Name_From_Path%
```

Result: Jones