# write files to relative path in DOS batch script

Tags: parameters, batch-file, relative-path

Referring to [What is the best way to do a substring in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636381/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-substring-in-a-batch-file) I think the below should work.

```
FOR %%f IN (*.wav) DO CALL :runthis "%%f"
rem del temp.wav tmpfile
GOTO :EOF

:runthis
set "outdir=%~p1\output\"
copy "%~1" "%outdir%%~1"
```

The last command is supposed to *dosomthing* to all .wav files in current directory and output to existing sub-directory "*output*" keeping the original filename. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

**Update1:** Thanks, fixed the syntax. I didn't notice that %pI expands **I** to path only, didn't read carefully. Now what's wrong is that it's expanded with the "s

```
dosomething "11.wav" "\Users\t4\Desktop\Airlines\WavRepeaters\\outdir\"11.wav""
```

It should be something like::

```
dosomething "11.wav" c:\Users\t4\Desktop\Airlines\WavRepeaters\outdir\11.wav
```

**Update2:** %~dp1       - expands %1 to a drive letter and path only, without the quotations!

Comment: First please tell us *what* exactly is wrong.

Comment: Anyway, `%~pI` usage is wrong indeed. What did you mean by it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem seems to be the use of the parameters.

In **:runthis** you use the `%~pI`, but there isn't any `%I`.
Another pitfall are spaces in the filenames, then dosomething need quotes around the filename / path.

With some changes it should work

```
@echo off
FOR %%f IN (*.bat) DO CALL :runthis "%%~f"
rem del temp.wav tmpfile
GOTO :EOF

:runthis
set "outdir=%~p1\output\"
echo dosomthing "%~1" "%outdir%%~1"
goto :eof
```