# Trim output in command prompt

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

***UPDATE: THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED. :)***

I want to trim a variable value in windows command prompt.

I used--

```
set str=sourav
echo %str:~0,3%
```

as mentioned on an online tutorial.

output--
sou

Can someone explain how this works? I mean how the colon and ~ are working here?

Comment: In a cmd prompt type `set /?` and read the help. It is explained in there.

Comment: i know how set works... i am talking about the second line echo %str:~0,3%

Comment: You didn't do as I said, or you wouldn't make that comment.

Comment: ohh...sorry... I did what you said and it is clear now. :) thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answered in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@foxidrive wrote:

> In a cmd prompt type `set /?` and read the help. It is explained in there.

@mofi noted its a duplicate of:

> [What is the best way to do a substring in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636381/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-substring-in-a-batch-file)