# how to batch move files date filename folder?

Tags: date, batch-file, directory, filenames, move

I have lots of image files named as YYYYMMDD_HHmm.jpg

How can I move these files to: target_directory\YYYY\MM\YYYYMMDD_HHmm.jpg ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop, substrings, and `mkdir`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') do (
    set filename=%%a

    ::exclude this file
    if not "!filename!" == "%~nx0" (

        ::substr to grab characters 0-4 and 4-6 as year and month
        set year=!filename:~0,4!
        set month=!filename:~4,2!

        ::make dirs for the files if they don't already exist
        if not exist !year! mkdir !year!
        if not exist !year!\!month! mkdir !year!\!month!

        ::move the files there
        move !filename! !year!\!month!
    )
)
```

The for loop runs `dir /b /a-d` which returns all files in the current directory except folders. Substring notation is `!variable:~start,length!`.

[What is the best way to do a substring in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636381/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-substring-in-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

One-liner for the command prompt:

```
for %a in (*.jpg) do @set "FName=%~a"&call xcopy "%FName%" "%FName:~0,4%\%FName:~4,2%\"&&del "%~a"&set "FName="
```