# How can I sort through a folder and move only specific files?

Tags: batch-file

I have a ton of .zip files in a folder that I want to move into a new folder I made IF it fulfills a certain condition in its name. Like, if it has the date inside the filename, I want to move it into the folder.
        cd C:\Users\eyousea\Documents\Test

```
    set today=%date:~10,13%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
    md %today%

    for %%a in (*.zip) do(
    set fileday=%%a:~1,8%
    if %today% = %fileday% (
    move %%a "C:\Users\eyousea\Documents\Test\%today%"

    pause
```

I'm not sure what's wrong. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It seems you are hitting the delayed expansion trap.  See [this page](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for more information.  See this question for a relevant example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594200/how-to-batch-move-files-date-filename-folder

Answer (score 1):

Use `echo on` and `echo AProblematicCommand` (for example `echo set fileday=%%a:~1,8%`) to debug batch-files!

1. The block closed in parentheses is parsed and `%`’s expanded at once. So the `fileday` value used in `if` contains its value before the `for` loop starts – probably undefined!

   You need to enable [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and use `!` to mark where to use it.
2. You have to put space between `do` and `(`.
3. A parameter like `%a` (or `%%a` in `for`) cannot be used for variable expansion. You have to assign it to a temporary variable and expand that.
4. You can use indentation in batch-files, just for readability. It helps to find unclosed parentheses, for example. I cannot see any `)` in your snippet.

To summarize:

```
set today=%date:~10,13%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
md %today%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.zip) do (
  set filename=%%a
  set fileday=!filename:~1,8!
  if %today% == !fileday! (
    move %%a "C:\Users\eyousea\Documents\Test\%today%"
  )
)
```

Comment: First off thanks for the explanation. However, it doesn't work. Just as a heads up, in the if statement it's a == instead of just a =, but I'm sure you would notice that. But more importantly, it says the syntax of the move statement is incorrect and won't move it. I think it's because the filename is just the file name and not the actual path. How would I amend that?

Comment: @Seanzies93 Thanks for `==`. The `move` syntax should be correct, unless there are spaces in the filename or something similar. Could you post an example of your `move` command after expansion and the error message?