# Batch Script Renaming File Prefix

Tags: windows, batch-file, renaming

I have a batch file that essentially finds all the pdf files in a folder, and gives them a prefix. SO example: `file1.pdf` & `file2.pdf`.  When the batch file runs, it adds a prefix, let's say "new" to each file. `New - file1.pdf` & `New - file2.pdf`.

I'm unsure of how to get this to check to see if this file already contains this prefix and skip it if true.
Here's my current code:

```
set strPrefix=New - 

set fname=*.pdf

for %%f in (%fname%) Do echo Rename file "%%f" to "%strPrefix%%%f"

for %%f in (%fname%) Do ren "%%f" "%strPrefix%%%f"
```

Comment: Have you tried a [substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636381/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-substring-in-a-batch-file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DIR /B to list the files and pipe the result to FINDSTR to remove the files that aready have the prefix. Process that result with FOR /F (instead of a simple FOR).

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "prefix=New - "
set "mask=*.pdf"

for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b "%mask%" ^| findstr /vibc:"%prefix%"'
) do ren "%%F" "%prefix%%%F"
```

Or you could use my [JREN.BAT regular expression file renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) to do things more simply. It is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is embedded within the script.

The following command (for the command line) assumes JREN.BAT is in a folder that is listed within your PATH.

```
jren "^" "New - " /fm "*.pdf" /fx "New - *"
```

Use CALL JREN if you put the command within a batch script.

Comment: Typo in `findstr /vibc:"%mask%"` should be `findstr /vibc:"%prefix%"`? The same in `ren`?

Comment: @JosefZ - Of course. How silly of me. All fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I was actually trying your suggestion and found out that &mask& needed to be %prefix% and was coming back to tell you but you beat me to it :)

Comment: @dbenham I can't seem to find the download link for JREN

Answer (score 0):

The following code extracts the beginning of the filename and compares it with your predefined prefix (in a case-insensitive manner):

```
set "strPrefix=New - "
set lenPrefix=6
set fname=*.pdf

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (%fname%) do (
  set "file=%%~nxF"
  if /i not "!file:~0,6!"=="%strPrefix%" (
    ren "%%~fF" "%strPrefix%%%~nxF"
  )
)
endlocal
```

The variable `lenPrefix` holds the length (number of characters) of the prefix, bacause there is no built-in function to get it.

Comment: This didn't appear to work. Nothing happens when it runs.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, @foxidrive!!