# How to get path of file with batch

Tags: batch-file, substr

I have a batch file that is stored in the `c:\data\profile\script.bat` directory. 
My script.dat contains :

```
@echo off
echo %~dp0%
pause
```

If I run it, will display on the screen `c:\data\profile\`. but that's not what I want. I want to display on the screen `c:\data\`. for that, I have change my batch contains to :

```
@echo off
echo %~dp0:~0,8%
pause
```

then I run the file , but the screen only displays `c:\data\profile\:~0,8`.
please let me know how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to do a substring in a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636381/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-substring-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: Have you tried what is written there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636381/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-substring-in-a-batch-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
@ECHO OFF
PUSHD
CD ..
ECHO %CD%
POPD
PAUSE
```

Your code will work if you modify it like this:

```
@echo off
set tempPath=%~dp0
echo %tempPath:~0,8%
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

I want explicitly one level up->

```
@echo off
set "the_folder=%~dp0"
for %%# in ("%the_folder:~0,-1%") do set "the_folder=%%~dp#"
echo %the_folder%
```

if you want the first folder in the path:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=\" %%# in ("%~dp0") do set "first_folder=%~d0\%%#"
echo %first_folder%
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to retrieve the parent (`..` is the reference to the parent folder) of the folder that contains the batch file (`%~dp0`), then your batch file could be something like

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    for %%a in ("%~dp0\..\") do echo %~fa
    pause
```