# What do you call this in windows batch file scripting? %VARIABLE:~2%

Tags: batch-file

What do you call this in batch file scripting ? `%VARIABLE:~2%`

So I'm trying to figure what this is specifically called when you set a variable, then select a position from that variable?

Example

```
SET TEST=FOO BAR 123
SET VAR=%TEST:~4,3%
```

And if I echo %VAR% I know it will return "BAR", but I have no idea what this is called, I just had to figure it out on my own by changing the values and checking what it returned.

Thank you.

Comment: Will this be helpful for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636381/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-substring-in-a-batch-file

Comment: I believe that's it! Never knew what it was called but that seems about right. Doing a search for "Variable Substring" results in what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps this link might help: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240] (c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Windows\system32>set /? 
>
> Displays, sets, or removes cmd.exe environment variables.
>
> SET [variable=[string]]
>
>   variable  
>
> Specifies the environment-variable name.   string    Specifies a series of characters to assign to the variable.
>
> Type SET without parameters to display the current environment variables.
>
> If Command Extensions are enabled SET changes as follows:
>
> ...
>  
> Environment variable substitution has been enhanced as follows:
>
>     %PATH:str1=str2%
>
> would expand the PATH environment variable, substituting each occurrence of "str1" in the expanded result with "str2".  "str2" can
> be the empty string to effectively delete all occurrences of "str1"
> from the expanded output.  "str1" can begin with an asterisk, in which
> case it will match everything from the beginning of the expanded
> output to the first occurrence of the remaining portion of str1.
>
> May also specify substrings for an expansion.
>
>     %PATH:~10,5%
>
> would expand the PATH environment variable, and then use only the 5 characters that begin at the 11th (offset 10) character of the
>  expanded result.  If the length is not specified, then it defaults to
> the remainder of the variable value.  If either number (offset or
> length) is negative, then the number used is the length of the
> environment variable value added to the offset or length specified.
>
>     %PATH:~-10%
>
> would extract the last 10 characters of the PATH variable.
>
>     %PATH:~0,-2%
>
> would extract all but the last 2 characters of the PATH variable.
>
> ...
>
> C:\Windows\system32>
> ```

Comment: In all my wisdom, not once did I think to do that. Ha.