# Remove Protocol-Handler from path in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, protocol-handler

I have a Protocol-Handler for our CRM which is like: "auftragmcc:123456?sven"

So if you press on the link, it opens our Invoice-Software with the current invoice (123456) and the correct user (sven).
Since we've changed something in the code of the invoice, we are still able to open it, but it won't go to the correct invoice.

in the registry id directs to an path on our server, which is similar on every device, and there is a batch which will execute the invoice-software with the correct start-parameters.

The batch looks like this:

```
@setLocal 
cd /d "Z:\PUBLIC\Auftrag_MegaCAD\"
start Auftrag.exe %1
```

but right now, in the %1 is the complete path with the handler instead of just the "123456?sven" part. How can i remove the "auftragmcc:" from this variable and just use the rest of it?

Comment: So you want to have a [substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636381/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-substring-in-a-batch-file)?

Comment: yes, i like to have a substring with the content after the "auftragmcc:" that i can use them as a startparameter for auftrag.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set str=%1
set %str:auftragmcc:=%
```