# Using a Batch file can you remove part of a file name from files in a folder and all sub folders?

Tags: batch-rename

Hi I am new at using batch files and I am struggling to find a way of removing part of a file name for multiple files in a folder and all sub-folder.

the files are all named like r1_c02_200111_145423_am.csv and I need to remove the _am from the files.

I have tried the following

```
FOR /R "C:\Users\bob\Documents\data\" %%G IN (*_am.csv) DO REN "%%G" *.csv
```

but this does not change anything.

can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of such a script, you can perform the required operation.

```
@ECHO off
FOR %%i IN (*_am.csv) DO CALL :do_rename %%i
GOTO :eof

:do_rename
SET "_file=%1"
REN "%_file%" "%_file:~0,-7%.csv"

:eof
```

Now more.

The search in the question was correct. To perform a rename while passing through the `FOR ... DO`, you can use both the `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` or a procedure call. I think it's easier to use a procedure call. you don’t have to puzzle over understanding (and misunderstanding) how the `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` works.

For each iteration of the loop, the Wick procedure is called with the first argument of the file name passed to it:

```
CALL :do_rename %%i
```

In the procedure itself, the argument is converted to a variable. You can already use substring operations on the variable itself. More information about substring operations can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/636391/5533907).

```
:do_rename
SET "_file=%1"
REN "%_file%" "%_file:~0,-7%.csv"
```